# Как с локального хостинга отправить запрос axios на Firebase, сейчас мешает CORS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, axios

Сейчас прохожу один из курсов по React и столкнулся с одной проблемой. Проблема заключается в том, что в связи с CORS правилами, я не могу с локального хоста обращаться к другому домену.

В сети много методов, но многие я не знаю как использовать в моём случае. Я использую дефолтный запуск приложения, который применяется в react: react-scripts start. Поэтому я не знаю куда мне вставлять код, связанный с node.js.

использую такую конструкцию

```
try { 
  const response = await axios.post('https://quiz-react-3618f.firebaseio.com/quizes', this.state.quiz) 
  console.log(response) 
} catch(e) { 
  console.log(e); 
}
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://quiz-react-3618f.firebaseio.com/quiz'
from origin 'https://quiz-react-3618f.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь этим сервисом для запросов https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае, ошибкой было то, что ссылка на запрос не содержит .json. URL должен выглядеть так: https://quiz-react-3618f.firebaseio.com/quizes**.json**

RavenTheX спасибо за ответ, теперь буду знать как обходить CORS при разработке)

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, можете проголосовать за него